# ClusterManager OnClusterClickListener not called

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

Good afternoon every one, I manage my google maps v2 with cluster manager(I'm using this library android-maps-utils) and I want to get the diffrence when a marker clicked and when a cluster manager clicked, But methodes doesn't called, So what going wrong in my code, I spent 10 days in this small problem, So Please Help.

HERE IT IS MY WHOLE CODE:

```
public class BigClusteringDemoActivity extends BaseDemoActivity implements ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener,ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener {
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;

    @Override
    protected void startDemo() {
        getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));

        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());

        getMap().setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
        try {
            readItems();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of markers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

    }


    private void readItems() throws JSONException {
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.radar_search);
        List<MyItem> items = new MyItemReader().read(inputStream);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            double offset = i / 60d;
            for (MyItem item : items) {
                LatLng position = item.getPosition();
                double lat = position.latitude + offset;
                double lng = position.longitude + offset;
                MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
                mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster cluster) {
        Log.d("cluster","clicked" + cluster.getItems());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClusterItemClick(ClusterItem item) {
        Log.d("cluster","clicked" + item.getPosition());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have not connected your ClusterManager to the map with onClick

You have this one  `getMap().setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);`

try adding these aswell

```
getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);`
```

This will use the implements for listeners you added.

Comment: I use them but i still not getting any result.

Comment: You said "here is my whole code" and those 3 lines are not there :) it will not register the listener if they aren't coupled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm just a beginner :) please except these lines what can cause the same problem ?

Comment: If you are beginner have you checked your android monitor for the log files? :) Nothing is supposed to happen now other than printing those to log

Comment: Thank you very much now it works, your confidence that there isn't any other Think that cause this problem led me remouved a doubt library and it worked.^^

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find sequence of ClusterManager initialization for click listeners finally work:

1) init maps

```
mMap = googleMap
```

2) init ClusterManager

```
mClusterManager = ClusterManager(requireContext(), mMap)
```

3) set Map OnMarkerClickListener

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager)
```

4) init ClusterManager

```
mClusterManager = ClusterManager(requireContext(), mMap)
```

5) set cluster click listeners

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener {
    println("CLUST ITEM CLICK")
    return@setOnClusterItemClickListener false
}
mClusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener {
    println("CLUST CLICK")
    return@setOnClusterClickListener false
}
```

6) when you use your custom render init it now:

```
mClusterManager.renderer = CustomIconRenderer(requireContext(), mMap, mClusterManager)
```

Comment: All this should be done inside `onMapReady` event. And why the 4th point is the same as 2nd? And what is `CustomIconRenderer`?